# Referring files in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I trying to refer the **english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger**(model file) to instantiate the tagger inside mapper in Hadoop Framework . I placed the file in HDFS .

```
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("tagger/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");
```

Comment: Welcome to SE ! Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour. Make your question understandable to be served better.

Comment: Access the file from mapper using Distribed cache in setup method of mapper